# Creating nested list with specific element shouldn't repeat if it already exist in previous list

Tags: python-3.x

I have the following list `list1 = [[1,2,3,4,5],[6,7,8,4,9],[5,6,7,8,9]]` .Now I want to create the new list like
 `list2 = [[1,2,3,4,5],[5,6,7,8,9]]` 
because I do not want index 1 list of list1 as its 4th element(4) is already exist in 0th index list of list1.
So how it can be done?

Comment: I'm not fully understanding the explanation - do you mean that the element `list1[0][3]` has the same index and value as the element `list1[1][3]` therefore you're removing the entire list `list1[1]`?

Comment: @ethanpasta....Exactly....You got it

Comment: And do I compare all the other lists with `list1[0]`? What if the same condition happens with items from `list1[1]` and `list1[2]`?

Comment: Yes....If element 4th is 4 then those other lists should also got remove.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
list1 = [[1,2,3,4,5],[6,7,8,4,9],[5,6,7,8,9]]
list2 = []
for l in list1:
  flag = True
  for existing in list2:
    if any(existing[i] == l[i] for i in range(len(existing))):
      flag = False
      break
  if flag:
    list2.append(l)
print (list2) # [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [5, 6, 7, 8, 9]]
```

Comment: Hi,,,your code works fine.But, what if another element [1,2,3,5,5] is also there in list1.and this should also include in list2 as its 4th element is not 4.How should it can be done

Comment: I figured it out

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `set` of index/value pairs as you traverse the list and then check against this set if any pair is already contained:

```
new = []
seen = set()
for lst in data:
    pairs = set(enumerate(lst))
    if not (pairs & seen):
        new.append(lst)
        seen |= pairs
```